# run phpunit of php-activerecord failed

Tags: php, phpunit, phpactiverecord

I am trying to test php-activerecord, it has some tests. When run:

phpunit sometestname

nothing happened. I checked the code,

```
include 'helpers/config.php';

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/Inflector.php';

class InflectorTest extends SnakeCase_PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

{
    public function set_up()
    {
        $this->inflector = ActiveRecord\Inflector::instance();
    }

    public function testOne()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(2+2==4);
    }
```

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: the master branch works for me, 3 tests, 5 assertions. Which version do you use? I'm running them on GNU/Linux though. `testOne` should be `test_one` apparently.

Comment: @greut No. Why should it have to be `test_one`? As long as it has test in front PHPUnit will consider it as a test.

Comment: if anything it should be public function setup() instead of set_up()

Comment: @Gordon `set_up` is working just fine: [InflectorTest.php](https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/blob/master/test/InflectorTest.php)

Comment: @greut that's not how PHPUnit does it.

Comment: @Gordon fair enough, I'll suggest a fix then to use the `setUp` found in the documentation. It's not the problem here, like `testOne` isn't either. PHPUnit 3.4.13 here btw.

Comment: @greut we figured it out in the chat. my answer below solved the issue for the OP.

Comment: tests are running with 3.5.13 as is too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PHPUnit version is a bit outdated. Let's make sure you are current. Please do

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
```

and then

```
pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit again
```

this should result in

```
downloading PHPUnit-3.5.13.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.5.13.tgz (118,553 bytes)
..........................done: 118,553 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.5.13
```

If there is any errors try upgrade your PEAR version to the current version with

```
pear upgrade-all
```

The [DocBlock for the test helper of PHPActiveRecord says](https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/blob/master/test/helpers/config.php)

```
/**
* In order to run these unit tests, you need to install:
* - PHPUnit
* - PEAR Log (otherwise logging SQL queries will be disabled)
* - Memcache (otherwise Caching tests will not be executed)
*
* To run all tests : phpunit AllTests.php --slow-tests
* To run a specific test : phpunit ????Test.php
*/
```

but there is two suppressed includes in it for the Log dependency

```
@include_once 'Log.php';
@include_once 'Log/file.php';
```

which could be the reason why you are not getting any result on CLI at all, so make sure you also do

```
pear install --force --alldeps Log
```

That should work then.

**EDIT:** the 1.0 Version that is available from the PHPActiveRecord Website does not have the above DocBlock and uses `require_once` for the Log dependency. This is changed in the current master version, so you might want to try the nightly or check out the master branch from GitHub:

- https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/commit/ea31eff9cd8ddbd23b7ce44d90e30b4e801d8590#test/helpers/config.php

Comment: `PEAR::Log` and `memcache` aren't required to run the tests especially not this one.

Comment: @greut see my edit. The 1.0 version available from the website has `require_once` calls for the Log dependency. For some reason, this was suppressed in the OPs installation, which is why there wasnt any errors.

Comment: yep, definitively use the master branch of the nightly.